# Global Search for tasks

Tags: search

According to the documentation, I should be able to use Global Search to search for text in task subject fields and task comment fields.  Neither of these seem to be working.  Does anyone have any idea why?

Thx,
Hamayoun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should show up as Activities. Also, make sure you click the Search All button, the first time you execute a global search it tends to use a subset of the searchable objects.

Comment: Thx Matthew!  Is there any way that we can force this to be the default for all users?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, the search has a "learning" feature where it will return different results for each user depending on how that user is interacting with the system. So the more you interact with Activities, the more likely they will be to return in the search results.